# Rails - change a controller's base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails, I am working on an existing project trying to add new features. I have generated a model using:

```
rails generate model PublisherOrg owner:string
```

I generated the controller using:

```
rails generate controller admin/publisher_orgs
```

Then in the routes file, I have added the following:

```
namespace :admin, path: '/admin' do
  root to: 'dashboard#index'

  resources :carriers
  resources :publisher_orgs
end
```

The problem that I have is that the controller file generated starts with

```
Admin::PublisherOrgsController < ApplicationController
```

For other controllers, however, it is like

```
Admin::CarriersController < Admin::BaseController
```

The inheritance is different. The problem is in that some of the methods are not visible for `PublisherOrgsController`.

After changing the controller file manually to start with:

```
Admin::PublisherOrgsController < Admin::BaseController
```

the "unknown methods" errors are resolved.

I want to know if what I have done is ok. I mean is changing the parent class manually enough or I need to do other things as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's it. Most likely `Admin::BaseController` inherits from `ApplicationController` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally fine to change the controller base class afterwards. I even think it is the only way to use the perks of inheritance on controllers as by my knowledge there is no option to let this be done in the 'rails g controller' call.

Always keep in mind that rails often looks like magic but deep down are just some cool ruby code ;) So if you want to change the base class of a rails controller there is nothing more to it than changing the base class of the ruby class that represents said controller.